# Whats up with my local ip address?

Tags: php, apache, ip, xampp, ip-address

I'm trying to create a PHP script for my homework.
I need the script to log ip addresses for security reasons.

For some reason, when I run the following code:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

The result is :

```
::1
```

I thought a localhost ip address was always like 127.0.0.1 ?

Does anyone know what is happening ? This is really bugging me and I can't seem to find a solution to the problem. Even google doesn't find anything related...

I should mention that I'm running an XAMPP installation on a windows 7 64bit machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast replies guys :)

Comment: So is there anyway possible to show my IPv4 address instead of IPv6 ? I tried editing my hosts file in windows, but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Try accessing it through http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7 localhost resolves to ::1 which is the ipv6 representation of 127.0.0.1

- Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
- Remove the following line, if present: ::1 localhost
- Add the following line, if not present: 127.0.0.1 localhost

if you also need mysql connection, it will help you to speed up the connection.

Comment: What about disabling ipv6 from your adapter settings?

Answer (score 8):

`::1` is an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)/localhost address, as `127.0.0.1` is for [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4). Your system can have an IPv4 *and* and IPv6 address if it is properly configured.

The fact that you're seeing this indicates that your sever is supporting IPv6. It may also be supporting IPv4. When a server has multiple addresses, magic globals like `REMOTE_ADDR` will only show one of them (typically the one which will be used by default).

Answer (score 4):

::1 is the localhost address under [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)
127.0.0.1 is the localhost address under [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

Answer (score 3):

This is your IPv6 address, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Answer (score 2):

::1 is the IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1. If you google IPv6, you should get a lot further. Good luck!